# Prepended input label (simple_form + bootstrap-sass) off by a few pixels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I want to use the text input field seen here:

http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/articles/new

(It's the second text input field on that page.)

I have it working in other Rails apps but for some reason in my current one there is a several-pixel gap between the prepended label and the text input. I've installed simple_form with the `--bootstrap` option, and have verified that the Rails/haml/bootstrap/bootstrap-sass versions are the same as the working rails app.

I don't override any of the related css in my stylesheets (I commented it all out to be sure).

Any ideas why Bootstrap isn't behaving as it should?

Comment: Exact same issue here. The bootstrap examples page works fine, but in  my 3.2 app I have 2-3 pixel gaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know what the problem is here, but I had the same thing.

Comparing the `span.add-on` tag I found that they had a `float: left` on theirs. I added that and it seemed to do the trick.

I also noticed they are using twitter 2.01. I'm using 2.02, so something might have changed.

EDIT: That messed up the append span.

```
.input-prepend .add-on,
.input-append input {
  float: left;
}
```

Is what I added. It doesn't feel right, but it's working for now. Hopefully someone else more knowledgeable of bootstrap can help out.

Answer (score 2):

I have not looked at the changes to see why, but I can confirm that it works as expected in 2.0.1 and has the described gap in 2.0.2. To revert to the old, correct behavior you can replace the existing bootstrap-sass line in your Gemfile with:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.1'
```

and update your bundle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this: `content_tag :span, "attribute", :class => "add-on", :style => 'margin-right: -5px;'`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up doing something like that. Still curious as to why I don't have to do that in all my other apps.

Comment: Thanks Bevan. Not sure either. I spent a bit of time trying to solve this for you.. would appreciate it if you would select this as your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yours is a good workaround, but I'm really looking for the solution to the root problem of why Bootstrap behaves strangely in my app. I'll make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution will cause problems if there is an error on the page due to validations. Simple_form actually has a wrapper that will allow you to do this and is much better when handling errors.

```
<%= f.input :name, :wrapper => :append, :class => "inline" do %>
    <%= f.input_field :name%>
    <%= content_tag :span, "@", :class => "add-on abbn" %>
<% end %>
```