# Append/prepend bootstrap icons with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Twitter Bootstrap icons are pretty deadly [seen here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons).

Look at the bottom right hand corner of that section. See that email with an icon prepended? That is what I want to do. I want to make simple_form and boostrap play nicely.

Here's what I've found that will prepend the icon to the input:

```
= f.input :email, :wrapper => :append do
  = f.input_field :email
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
```

But it isn't flush (that could be fixed by changing offsets in CSS) and it's pretty ugly. For reference, here is the CSS fix (add it to your bootstrap_overrides.css.less file):

```
.input-prepend .add-on,
.input-append input {
  float: left; }
```

Does someone know a less hacky way to make simple_form prepend or append an icon with bootstrap?

#### Update:

The answer below made me have another look at it. HAML usually adds whitespace everywhere, but there is a [workaround](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_)

Here is an update for the original HAML which removes the whitespaces and doesn't require the CSS hack:

```
= f.input :email, :wrapper => :append do
  = f.input_field :email
  %span.add-on>
    %i.icon-envelope
```

That little greater than (>) makes all the difference. The output HTML has no newlines between the input and the span.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033572/prepended-input-label-simple-form-bootstrap-sass-off-by-a-few-pixels

Comment: Instead of `%span(class="add-on")` you can write `%span.add-on` (same with `icon-envelope`)

Comment: and for prepend I used %span.add-on> @ \n = f.text_field :twitter

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's due to whitespace between the rendered `input` and `span` elements. In this case, a line break.

I am not familiar enough with HAML to tell you how to eliminate the whitespace, but the equivalent ERB would go something like:

```
<%= f.input :email, :wrapper => :append do %>
  <%= f.input_field :email %><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: HAML can process ERB directly using **:erb** and indenting.

However, you pushed me in the right direction for figuring this out. Here is a working solution (see original post's update).

Comment: With this approach you lose the placeholder and other options, that's sad :(

Comment: Yeah, any idea how to get the other options (placeholder, etc) in there?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a better way to do this, to keep `placeholder`, `label`, and other options intact.

For those that are still using old Bootstrap 2.3.x

```
<div class="input-prepend">
  <span class="add-on">@</span>
  <%= f.input_field :password, :required => true, :label=>false, :placeholder=>"Password" %>
</div>
```

The key is using `f.input_field` to remove all div wrappers.

**UPDATE**

You can use the other solution to include a placeholder, but you cannot remove the label using that solution.

```
<%= f.input :email, :wrapper => :append do %>
  <%= f.input_field :email, placeholder: "hello" %><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
<% end %>
```