# Trouble using simple_form between input and =f.input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, slim-lang

[image]

this is the screenshot of below slim simple_form form. this shows properly. But this gives me type nil error.

```
  = simple_form_for :identity, :url => '/auth/identity/register' do |f| 
  h2 Create New Account

  .form-actions
    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-user
          input type="text", label:false, :class => "inline"

    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-user
          input type="text" id="" name="" f:email


    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-user
          input type="text" id="" name="" f:password

    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-user
          input type="text" id="" name="" f:password_confirmation

    .control-group
        .controls
          = f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary'
```

[image]

this is screenshot of below code. this works fine(not gives nil type error. because it takes model fields.) But appearence is broken down.

```
= simple_form_for :identity, :url => '/auth/identity/register' do |f| 
  h2 Create New Account

  .form-actions
    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-user
          =f.input :name, label:false

    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-user
          = f.input :email, label:false


    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-user
          = f.input :password, label:false

    .control-group
      .controls
        .input-prepend
          span.add-on
            i.icon-user
          = f.input :password_confirmation, label:false

    .control-group
        .controls
          = f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary'
```

Comment: may be  "=f.input :name, label:false" this line of code '=' and 'f' is  not separated by space here.

Comment: Have you noticed that?

Comment: i notice it. But trouble isn't that.

Comment: You should stick with the model fields and drill into the HTML with some CSS styling to get the fields to look that way you want.

Comment: Did you check your source code? Your input is probably in a div (which is the default case with simple_form), and div is a block element.

Answer (score 1):

You can get simple_form to generate twitter bootstrap forms by using the install generator

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

You don't have to do that, but it makes your form much simpler! See the docs https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Then to answer your actual question, you can prepend your user icon like this

```
= f.input :email, :wrapper => :append do
  = f.input_field :email
   %span.add-on>
     %i.icon-user
```

The > after the add-on stops haml putting in a new line which would separate the span and the input.  See this answer for more detail [Append/prepend bootstrap icons with simple_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547502/append-prepend-bootstrap-icons-with-simple-form)